# With pre-commit, how to use some hooks before commit and others before push

Tags: python, git, pre-commit-hook, pre-commit, pre-commit.com

Some hooks can take a while to run, and I would like to run those before I push, but not before each particular commit (for example, pylint can be a bit slow).

I've seen the following:

- [Question: Using hooks at different stages](https://github.com/pre-commit/pre-commit/issues/768)
- [mesos-commits mailing list archives](http://mail-archives.apache.org/mod_mbox/mesos-commits/201909.mbox/%3C20190918105238.5D6C581D0B@gitbox.apache.org%3E)
- [Feature request: pre-commit or pre-push only hooks](https://github.com/pre-commit/pre-commit/issues/255)

But it's still not clear to be how I'm supposed to set this up.

Here is what I have tried:

```yml
default_stages: [commit]
repos:
  - repo: https://github.com/pre-commit/pre-commit-hooks
    rev: v3.1.0
    hooks:
      - id: end-of-file-fixer
      - id: trailing-whitespace
  - repo: https://github.com/psf/black
    rev: 19.10b0
    hooks:
      - id: black
        stages: [push]
```

From that I'm expecting the first couple of hooks to run before a commit (which they do), but I'm expecting black to run before pushing, which it doesn't.

To test that I have created the following file:

```py
"""This is a docstring."""

print('this should be formatted')
```

Which is certainly not being formatted by black.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

your configuration is correct, except that the whitespace hooks in `pre-commit/pre-commit-hooks` [set `stages` themselves](https://github.com/pre-commit/pre-commit-hooks/blob/31d41ff29115a87808277ee0ec23999b17d5b583/.pre-commit-hooks.yaml#L127) so they won't be affected by `default_stages`

adjusting your configuration slightly:

```yaml
repos:
  - repo: https://github.com/pre-commit/pre-commit-hooks
    rev: v3.1.0
    hooks:
      - id: end-of-file-fixer
        stages: [commit]
      - id: trailing-whitespace
        stages: [commit]
  - repo: https://github.com/psf/black
    rev: 19.10b0
    hooks:
      - id: black
        stages: [push]
```

next you'll need to make sure **both** of the hook scripts are installed

You can install both the `pre-commit` and `pre-push` commit at the same time using:

```
pre-commit install --hook-type pre-commit --hook-type pre-push
```

or you can run them separately:

```sh
pre-commit install  # installs .git/hooks/pre-commit
pre-commit install --hook-type pre-push  # installs .git/hooks/pre-push
```

note that the second command comes directly from [the documentation on using pre-push](https://pre-commit.com/#pre-commit-during-push)

---

disclaimer: I'm the author of pre-commit and pre-commit-hooks

Comment: Thanks @anthony, this works : ).

However, if `default_stages` applies to all stages, why is it necessary to specify `--hook-type` for these 2 stages? 

I had this very same problem and my expectation, after reading the doc, was that by not specifying any stages globally, pre-commit would install the hooks configured at the specified stages. 

Why isn't this so?

Comment: @JulianB. `default_stages` is only the fallback value for `stages` when unspecified, it does not "applies to all stages" -- it's entirely unrelated to `--hook-type`.  some hooks specify `stages` that's more broad than the hooks you're actually using so taking that at face value for `install` would be incorrect.  also pre-commit would need to clone / install repos to even get that info (which is intentionally not part of `install` unless `--install-hooks`) so it's technically infeasible.  there's a bunch of dupes in the issue tracker you can search there